# RavenDB - How to know if a Store(entity) created or updated an entity?

Tags: ravendb

Anyway to know if a `DocumentSession.Store(entity)`; `DocumentSession.SaveChanges()` created or updated the entity? The `id` and the state of the entity is always the one being stored (I will never need to load before storing).

Looking at fliddler the only thing that changes is the etag (as expected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to know, nothing in RavenDB really cares if the document exists already or being created.

Comment: Any tips in implementing a PUT in a webapi? i whould like to return 201 for new documents and 200 for modified ones.

Comment: You would have to check for it first.